# What is the reason that I have to use another variable name to have my code run?

Tags: python

I am a python newbie -.-
The following code is what I write on leetcode:

```
def postorderTraversal(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        result, stack, current, last_traversed = [], [], root, None
        while stack or current:
            if current:
                stack.append(current)
                current = current.left
            else:
                parent = stack[-1]
                if parent.right in (None, last_traversed):
                    result.append(parent.val)
                    last_traversed = stack.pop()
                else:
                    current = parent.right
        return result
```

It works apparently, but I used to replace all `parent` with `current` and the program gives me the result of "Time Limit Exceeded".

What I was wondering is why I can't simply use `current` throughout the code. Why I have to create another variable for the parent node?

Comment: Because `current` is already used for another role, and a single variable can't have two values?

Comment: But at least "current = current.right" works for my preorder and inorder code.

Comment: I have no idea what you're referring to by that comment. If you write into `current` instead of `parent`, you'll overwrite the value stored in `current`, and therefore will obviously get the wrong result the next time you need its original value.

Comment: Why do you need to reuse `current`?  There's nothing wrong with having separate variables for separate purposes.  If you include your preorder and inorder code we can help explain why your postorder is different.

Comment: Please learn to format your code and check the result before posting.

Comment: By the way, this is already your fourth question and second month on this site. You can take the two minutes to learn how to format code properly.

Comment: Yes, that's my bad, and now I know ctrl-k will do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the branch that begins with `if parent.right`, `parent` is set but `current` is not. So if you replace it with `current` the behavior is different.

Answer (score 1):

If stack is true, current is False and stack[-1].right is one among None and last_traversed you don't want current to be modified.

This is a question about the algorithm, not about the language.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and yes it's truly an algorithm question...my bad.